# real-time update in ionic framework using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently using $interval on request http.get to get the files from mysql server. is this a good choice or not ? what can you suggest ?

Comment: Why not use websockets? That way you do not have to keep polling.

Comment: how do i get started with websockets with mysql ?

Comment: check out http://socket.io/

Comment: why should i use socket.io ? what is the difference when using socket.io and just using interval on angularjs  through php mysql database. ?

Comment: how does socket.io refrain from polling the server

Comment: I'd recommend googling websockets vs http polling

Comment: i have now connection with node through the app.. should i still use interval on angular to acess the data.. inside the interval function will be the socket.on()